# floating elements ignoring larger element

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
.smallColumn{
  float:left;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline;
}
.largeColumn{
  width: 1700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="smallColumn" id="1">Small</div>
  <div class="smallColumn" id="2">Small</div>
  <div class="smallColumn" id="3">Small</div>

  <div class="largeColumn">Large</div>

  <div class="smallColumn" id="4">Small</div>
  <div class="smallColumn" id="5">Small</div>
  <div class="smallColumn" id="6">Small</div>
  <div class="smallColumn" id="7">Small</div>
  <div class="smallColumn" id="8">Small</div>
</div>
```

I want as many small columns in a row that fit the screen. How many, depends on the size of the screen its viewed on. The large column has to be on the row below of the small column it follows and cover the enire row. Any remaining small columns should be displayed on the rows below it. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Edit: 
I dont seem to have explained my question very well. So an example:

The large column should be displayed on the row below the third small column, so its below it in the code. 
When displayed on a normal screen there is room on the first row for another 3 elements (i numbered them just to be clear). I want columns 4,5 and 6 to ignore the large column and be displayed on the first row as well. Since columns 7 and 8 dont fit on the first row, they should be displayed in a row below the large column. 
On a slighly larger screen there would be room for column 7 on the first row, so it should be displayed there as well.

Comment: Quick question, do you know the height of the columns (even in the different media queries?)

Answer (score 0):

Using floats to layouts cause break-layout problems if you don't understand fine how it works.

First of all, you don't need to put `display:inline` because floated elements are `block` elements automatically.

To fix your problem is defining float to large:

```
.largeColumn{
  float:left;
  width: 1700px;
}
```

Or the other solution, is remove floated elements and transform it to `display: inline-block`

Comment: Sorry, this is as the old far west :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should also add float: left to .largeColumn. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Just add `clear:both` to `.largeColumn` (you don't have to specify `width` but of course you can):

```
.largeColumn{
    clear: both;
}
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear:

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to
>   floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared)
>   below them.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is using clear:both for the large element.

```
.largeColumn{clear: both;}
```

I would suggest running through MDN - float/clear, as floating elements can get tricky: [MDN - float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3ft6yu4/6/) using your code.

Comment: If there is any room left on the first row, I want small columns below the large column to move next there. Any small columns that dont fit on that row, i want to be displayed below the large column

Answer (score 0):

Try flexbox.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.smallColumn {
  flex-basis: 300px;
}

.largeColumn {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
  <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
  <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>

  <div class="largeColumn">Large</div>

  <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
  <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
  <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
  <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
  <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tip using flex. I managed to get my solution. Not the prettiest solution, but works

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
    <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
    <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>

    <div class="largeColumn"><div class="contentDiv">test test</div></div>
    <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
    <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
    <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
    <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
    <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
    <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
    <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
    <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
    <div class="smallColumn">Small</div>
</div>
.container {
display: flex;
flex-flow: wrap;
height: 60px;
}
.smallColumn {
flex-basis: 300px;
align-self: flex-start;
background-color: yellow;
}

.largeColumn {
flex-basis: 1px;
align-self: flex-start;
background-color: orange;
margin-top: 30px;
}

.contentDiv
{
background-color: orange;
position: absolute;
left:10px;
flex-basis: 600px;
}
```